# 'Parameter is not valid' exception while trying to create TIFF from pdf-byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

Code:

```
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\AISB08.pdf");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, true);
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        try
        {
            System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(ms).Save(@"C:\test2.tiff", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff); 
         **// GETTING EXCEPTION IN THE ABOVE SAVE STATEMENT**
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
        }
```

Q1: I am getting the ArgumentException 'Parameter is not valid' exception while trying to create TIFF from byte array created from pdf file. How can I solve it?

Q2: If creating byte from pdf and write it into TIFF is not possible directly, then help me on achieving this without any third party dlls/purchase. Or any free open source .Net project available which I  can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\AISB08.pdf");
```

Your `bytes` variable is not holding tiff format data, it is having a pdf format. You need to pass a valid tiff format data to `Image.FromStream` to make it work.

Comment: How can I convert the PDF to TIFF then?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea about that, you may ask new question or bit of google can help